# Transparent proxy to other IP of thousand ports

Tags: iptables, proxy, curl, squid, tunneling

I was bought a service that only allow a IP, the IP that i say, only one, but I need use this from more IP's. I think that I can install in this computer a system to do a transparent proxy for redirect my socks5 requests to this IP from other IP.

For example, I can buy a server and allow this IP in the service, and later use my home or office computer to access using the server as a tunnel.

And I need respect the ports.

My home IP -> Server allowed IP -> Service computer

My home IP does a request to the IP of server (example: 80.90.70.60): curl -x 80.90.70.60:50000 And my server will do a proxy to service computer (example: 100.120.130.110) with the same port (50000) and the response go back to my curl response.

How can I do this?